# What does port forwarding mean in "SSH port forwarding"?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

1. Wikipedia says

   > In computer networking, **port forwarding** or port mapping is an application of network address translation (NAT) that redirects a
   >   communication request from one address and port number combination
   >   to another while the packets are traversing a network gateway, such
   >   as a router or firewall.

   Does the definition of port forwarding apply to "SSH port
   forwarding"?

   What does "port forwarding" mean in SSH local and remote port
   forwarding?
2. In particular **what** is forwarded to **what** by
   **what**?

   For example. In https://askubuntu.com/a/50075/1471,

   > The command for forwarding port 80 from your local machine (localhost) to the remote host on port 8000 is ssh -R
   >   8000:localhost:80 oli@remote-machine.

   Would you say the same thing, or will you say "forwarding port 8000
   on the remote host to port 80 on local machine"?

Comment: do you have a specific context or are you trying to understand about the process in general? the definition from wikipedia is a good one. Basically you have one device (on a home network - a router) which intercepts packets and literally rewrites the header metadata of the packet, then "forwards" it to the internal machine - as per the internal network machines ip address. the router then keeps a track of the external remote machine and the internal machine in a table - because when the internal machine responds the router has to rewrite the packet on the way back out too

Comment: More to understand what other people mean by "forwarded port" and other words containing "forward(ed)", than how to use SSH port forwarding.

Answer (score 14):

## 1 - general case

Suppose you have two server in a company network.

From local server "L1" you have access to a remote server "R1" via ssh on port 22.

1. The server R1 host a web service, but firewall/NAT/whatever block direct access to port 80.
2. "R1" can't access "L1" directly due to NAT issue.

from  L1 you connect using (same user on both host)

```
ssh -L 10080:localhost:80 -R 10022:localhost:22 R1
```

now,

- `-L 10080:localhost:80` local browsing on 10080 will be forward to distant host (R1), localhost (e.g. distant 127.0.0.1) on port 80, thus you could browse distant host (R1), while blocked by firewall/NAT.
- `-R 10022:localhost:22` remote use of port 10022 will be forwarded to localhost (L1) port 22, you  can initiate scp/ssh from remote to localhost. (using `scp -P 10022 file localhost:` (note upper `-P` ) )

> This is actually a command line I use from an Ubuntu (14.04) laptop to go to production server (I can firefox to localhost:10080 and use scp from server to localhost:10022 to bring back file )

now your IP are

```
192.168.1.1 L1
172.17.17.1 R1
```

you use

```
ssh -L 10080:172.17.17.3:80 -R 10022:192.168.1.5:22 \
     -L 192.168.1.9:8888:172.17.17.9:9999 R1
```

now

- distant access to port 10022 (any IP) will be forwarded to local 192.168.1.5 ssh/scp.
- local access to port 10080 (any IP) will be forwarded to distant host 172.17.17.3 port 80.
- local access to port 8888 from 192.168.1.9 will be forwarded to port 9999 on 172.17.17.9 (192.168.1.9 is a local address in L1, using alias mecanism, this is not a firewall rule).

those setting can be used on putty/bitwise client
[image: Port forwarding on putty]

## Ask Ubuntu question

what  about

```
 -R 8000:localhost:80
```

this read as

- `-R` remote
- `8000` port 8000 (remote port 8000 ... )
- `localhost`  (remote port 8000 goest to localhost .. )
- `80` ( remote port 8000 goes to localhost port 80 )

Comment: Thanks. I like to clarify my questions a little with an example. In http://askubuntu.com/a/50075/1471, "the command for **forwarding** port 80 from your local machine (localhost) **to** the remote host on port 8000 is `ssh -R 8000:localhost:80 oli@remote-machine`". Would you   say the same thing, or will you say "**forwarding** port 8000 on the remote host **to** port 80 on local machine"?